# Subtract every column from each other in an xts object

Tags: r, xts

I am a newbie learning to code and have an xts object of 1000 rows and 10 columns.  I need to subtract every column from each other creating a new xts object keeping the date column.  I've tried to use combn but could not get it to create B-A result since it did A-B. What I'm looking for is below.

```
 DATA                                           RESULT
            A  B   C     --->               A-B   A-C  B-A  B-C  C-A  C-B
2010-01-01  1  3   5           2010-01-01   -2    -4    2    -2    4    2 
2010-01-02  2  4   6           2010-01-02   -2    -4    2    -2    4    2
2010-01-03  3  5   2           2010-01-03   -2     1    2     3   -1   -3
```

Comment: You can try with `outer` to get all the combinations of the column names.

Comment: Akrun- not familiar with outer.  using test as xts object I tried: z<- outer(colnames(test)[2:ncol(test)], test, function(x) test[[x[1]]] - test[[x[2]]])

Comment: Posted a solution below.  Hope it helps

Comment: For an `xts` object, there is no column called 'Date'.  It should be `index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the data using:

```
x <- zoo::zoo(
    data.frame(
        A = c(1, 2, 3), 
        B = c(3, 4, 5), 
        C = c(5, 6, 2)), 
    order.by = as.Date(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03")))
```

Then I defined a function for creating all possible pairs of two sets:

```
cross <- function(x, y = x) {

    result <- list()

    for (a in unique(x)) {

        for (b in unique(y)) {

            result <- append(result, list(list(left = a, right = b)))
        }
    }

    result
}
```

To answer your question:

```
# Build a list of column combinations
combinations <- cross(names(x), setdiff(names(x), names(x)[1]))

# Remove any entries where the left equals the right
combinations <- combinations[vapply(combinations, function(x) { x$left != x$right }, logical(1))]

# Build a user friendly list of names
names(combinations) <- vapply(combinations, function(x) { paste0(x$left, "-", x$right) }, character(1))

# Do the actual computation and combine the results into one object 
do.call(cbind, lapply(combinations, function(x, data) { data[, x$left, drop = T] - data[, x$right, drop = T] }, data = x))
```

Comment: This worked great.  I'm now trying to work through the logic so I can become a better programmer.  Thank you and akrun for your help and fast responses. Doug

Comment: In RStudio, click on a function and press F1 to read more about it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `outer` to get pairwise combinations of the column names, `subset` the dataset 'xt1' based on the column names, get the difference in a `list`.

```
f1 <- Vectorize(function(x,y) list(setNames(xt1[,x]-xt1[,y],
                                         paste(x,y, sep='_'))))
lst <- outer(colnames(xt1), colnames(xt1), FUN = f1)
```

We `Filter` out the `list` elements that have `sum=0` i.e. the difference between columns `A-A`, `B-B`, and `C-C`, and `cbind` to get the expected output.

```
 res <- do.call(cbind,Filter(sum, lst))
 res[,order(colnames(res))]
 #            A_B A_C B_A B_C C_A C_B
 #2010-01-01  -2  -4   2  -2   4   2
 #2010-01-02  -2  -4   2  -2   4   2
 #2010-01-03  -2   1   2   3  -1  -3
```

#### data

```
 d1 <- data.frame(A=1:3, B=3:5, C=c(5,6,2))
 library(xts)
  xt1 <- xts(d1, order.by=as.Date(c('2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03')))
```

Comment: akun- my xts object test when I use str(test) after xts Attributes: it says List  of 2                                                                                                                $ src    : chr "yahoo"
$ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2015-08-10 14:00:08"                so when i try your code using test it gives me NULL.  is this the reason?  If so any suggestions on how to fix?  Thanks

Comment: @doug Anyway, I created an xts object based on what you showed and got the exact output you showed.

Comment: @doug Are you talking about the `NULL` in the `dimnames` attribute?  In my case it is NULL because I didn't create one.